# Delete from current position to the beginning of line in emacs?

Tags: emacs

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> would delete everything from the current position of the cursor to the end of line. Is there some equivalence to delete everything from the current position to the beginning of line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For me <kbd>Ctrl-0</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd> does what you want.  I think this is the default configuration, it's certainly not something I've modified.

If this doesn't work try <kbd>Ctrl-u</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-k</kbd>.  Again, that seems to be Emacs' default behaviour on my installation (Emacs 24.x, Mac OS X).

Comment: Doesn't work for me... Hmm.. It would only delete from the current position to the end of line (because of `C-k` , the 'prefix' `C-0` didn't seem to have any effects)

Comment: Also `M-0 C-k` I think this was the first keybinding you meant. `M-arg` normally serves as a shorthand for `C-u arg command`.

Comment: @wvxvw: nope, I meant the key-binding I wrote, it works for me. See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackwardKillLine

Comment: Hm... interesting, didn't know that.

Comment: All I needed was `C-u`.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to have lesser keybinding (rather than having separate key to delete line, or having to invoke prefix-argument). You can use [crux-smart-kill-line](https://github.com/bbatsov/crux/blob/308f17d914e2cd79cbc809de66d02b03ceb82859/crux.el#L199)
which will "kill to the end of the line and kill whole line on the next
call". But if you prefer `delete` instead of `kill`, you can use the
code below.

For point-to-string operation (kill/delete) I recommend to use [zop-to-char](https://github.com/thierryvolpiatto/zop-to-char)

```lisp
(defun aza-delete-line ()
  "Delete from current position to end of line without pushing to `kill-ring'."
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (point) (line-end-position)))

(defun aza-delete-whole-line ()
  "Delete whole line without pushing to kill-ring."
  (interactive)
  (delete-region (line-beginning-position) (line-end-position)))

(defun crux-smart-delete-line ()
  "Kill to the end of the line and kill whole line on the next call."
  (interactive)
  (let ((orig-point (point)))
    (move-end-of-line 1)
    (if (= orig-point (point))
        (aza-delete-whole-line)
      (goto-char orig-point)
      (aza-delete-line))))
```

[source](https://github.com/azzamsa/scripts.el#smart-delete-line)

Answer (score 0):

Emacs has steep learning curve. When a new user encounters this problem, she should record a macro of 2 keystrokes: Shift+Ctrl+a and Ctrl-w (cut), name it, save it, and set up a key binding so that the macro is available in the subsequent Emacs sessions.

Comment: Point being: Learn to record macros and save them in your .emacs.d for later use.